Three.js Cube Render displays nothing
I'm trying to render a cube with Three.js. I wrote the code exactly as stated in the tutorial from tutorialspoint and I'm getting a blank screen.
I'm trying to render the code, but nothing displays onto the screen. Here's the code. The result is a blank screen, the problem is I'm not too sure where the problem is. I can try adding semicolons to the script code but it didn't work before.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Intro to Three JS</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        }
        
        html, body {
            height:100vh;
            width:100vw;
        }
        
        #threejs-container {
            position:block;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="threejs-container">
        <!--Our output to be rendered here-->


    </div>


    <script type="module">
        //Our Javascript goes here
        //Sizes
        const width = window.innerWidth
        const height = window.innerHeight
        //Scene
        const scene = new THREE.Scene()
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x262626)

        //Camera

        const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, width/height, 0.1, 100)
        camera.position.set(0,0,10)

        //Creating a Cube
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,2,2)
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe:true})

        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        scene.add(cube)

        //Renderer
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer()
        renderer.setSize(width,height)
        renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

        

        //Render the scene
        const container = document.querySelector('#threejs-container')
        container.append(renderer.domElement)
        renderer.render(scene,camera)

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>

Tried rendering and won't render.

Because you don’t have now access to classes, etc., provided by Three.js. ;)
Change from:
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, width/height, 0.1, 100)
        camera.position.set(0,0,10)

To:
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 100);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera
Keep in mind, that following 1to1 tutorial, which based on quite old version of Three.js, would make you potential troubles in future.

Thanks! I changed perspectiveCamera to THREE.PerspectiveCamera and still, same occurence.

@Skymasta Code works… https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/full/eYaELNG

Thats great, but why won't it work in VsCode?
